# Oracle date formatting

Tags: c#, oracle

in my c# programme i am requesting data from an oracle database and one field is the date abd time in this format - `12/09/2008 15:11:17` , is there anyway i can just return the date?

Is there also a way of ensuring its in british format, by modifying the sql to be dd/mm/yyyy

thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could get the date part of the `DateTime` using C#, You could do

```
string date = MyDateTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");///let MyDateTime be your DateTime variable
```

If you want to do in Oracle, you can use `to_char` for example,

```
select to_char(sysdate, 'dd/MM/yyyy') From dual;
```

Comment: very nice. i like the DateTime object. having sites like this really is useful because i doubt would have ever encountered that again if not.

Answer (score 5):

The Oracle trunc() function removes the time part:

```
select trunc(datecol) from mytable;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your sql query to oracle you can

```
to_date('12/09/2008 15:11:17', 'dd/MM/yyyy')
```

where you replace the date with your field in the oracle db.

Alternatively, you can handle it on the C# side with formatting

```
CultureInfo ukCulture = new CultureInfo("en-GB");

//this assuming you do not have a datetime type
DateTime myDateTime = DateTime.Parse("12/09/2008 15:11:17", ukCulture.DateTimeFormat);

string result = myDateTime.ToString(ukCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern));
```